# sql query to find record that contains IDs of other records in the same Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a SQL query against an Oracle 11 database that will retrieve records where one record itself has values under separate columns which hold the auto-generated ID(s) of one or more other records in the same table.

So, the records in the table would look something like this:

```
| FOREIGN_PARTY_ID | ORG_NAME | RELATED_PARTY_ID1 | RELATED_PARTY_ID2 | ...
| 1001             | null     | null              | null              | ...
| 1002             | null     | null              | null              | ...
| 1003             | null     | null              | null              | ...
| 1004             | null     | null              | null              | ...
| 1005             | ABC, INC. | 1001             | 1002              | 1003      | 1004
```

Comment: May be `UNION` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) is what you are looking for. But it'd be much better if you provide a more detailed example ...

Comment: My apologies, should have added that. The output will be displayed in a primefaces form with output labels and their respective input fields containing the information retrieved from the database via that query. So, for example, an output labels / input field would be **Organization : ABC, INC.**, another would be **First Name : John    Last Name : Doe**, etc...The records returned will be stored in a list from which I will then populate the appropriate fields on the primefaces form. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both for replying. @Trinimon: I will check out the link. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This query will return all rows in your table, which contains an auto-generated ID from FOREIGN_PARTY_ID in at least one RELATED_PARTY_IDn field:

```
SELECT
  t.*, 
  t1.*, /* actually, you can specify only fields you need */
  t2.*, 
  ...,
  tn.*
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME t
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE_NAME t1 ON t1.RELATED_PARTY_ID1 = t.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE_NAME t2 ON t2.RELATED_PARTY_ID2 = t.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID
...
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE_NAME tn ON tn.RELATED_PARTY_IDn = t.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID
WHERE
    t1.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID IS NOT NULL 
 OR t2.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID IS NOT NULL 
 OR ...
 OR tn.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to get only the rows which contains your IDs in EVERY RELATED_PARTY_IDn field, you can change `OR` in the `WHERE` conditions by `AND`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! The "challenge" is that all, or one or more of those RELATED_PARTY_ID fields could be null. The end user has the choice of not entering any data, or completing one or more fields (tied to RELATED_PARTY_ID), so any of those fields could be null, or have data in them. In other words, its not a straightforward thing where all or no fields will be filled in. Anyway, between Trinimon's suggestion of using UNION and now your details above I have some ideas to work on. Thank you once again!!!!!  :-)

Comment: Hi @denied, one more question. Your query works, except I need one more record - the one containing the RELATED_PARTY_IDn ids from the FOREIGN__PARTY_IDs of the other records. If you go back to my original diagram that's the row with the FOREIGN_PARTY_ID of **1005**, and ORG_NAME of **ABC, INC.**. I refer to that as the "master" row because, in essence, it has the FOREIGN_PARTY_IDn of the other rows under one of the RELATED_PARTY_IDn columns of this "master" row. Thanks again!